# How to access Extjs 4 store base properties

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

How can I access custom root property from the store like built in properties such as idProperty, totalProperty, messageProperty etc. Please check the code for ref.

```
Ext.define('app.store.Reviews', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'app.model.Review',
    pageSize: 200,
    remoteSort: true,
    // allow the grid to interact with the paging scroller by buffering
    buffered: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'review/list',
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            root: 'list',
            totalProperty: 'count',
            myCustomproperty: 'fieldInJson' // Somewhat like this
        },
        filterParam: 'query'
    }
});
```

update: also I could be able to access the property via store

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, are you trying to get access to other data returned in the json response that is not in the `list` node?

Comment: @weeksdev Yup right I want to access other data in the json response that is not in list node, how can I access data other than which are specified in reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsonData` object is available from the `proxy.reader`.  You could access this data in the store `load` event by adding listener:

```
Ext.define('app.store.Reviews', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'app.model.Review',
    pageSize: 200,
    remoteSort: true,
    // allow the grid to interact with the paging scroller by buffering
    buffered: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'review/list',
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            root: 'list',
            totalProperty: 'count'
        },
        filterParam: 'query'
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function (store,records,successful,eOpts) {
            //older
            console.log(store.proxy.reader.jsonData);
            //4.2
            console.log(store.getProxy().getReader().jsonData);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In 4.2, you need to call `store.getProxy()`

Comment: @MattGreer modify answer for 4.2.  I tested and appears to work.  Let me know if there is anything you think could be added?

Comment: Looks good. That's just a minor gotcha I found in 4.2. I'm pretty sure you can also use `getProxy()` and `getReader()` in 4.1 and below. Seems safest to use getters if they exist.

Comment: So I can only access it in the load event! I was accessing it in the controller this way so it wasn't working `this.getStore('Reviews').getProxy().getReader().jsonData` - this doesn't work

Comment: Provided the store is loaded, you should be able to access in the controller like this `Ext.getStore('store').getProxy().getReader().jsonData`